# How to build an APEX (Android Pony EXpress) module

Tags: android, android-source

I have the [DNSResolver apex module](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/DnsResolver/+/refs/heads/android12-mainline-resolv-release) downloaded for Android 12. It has all keys and manifests ready to go. The `Android.bp` file is as follows

```
package {
    // See: http://go/android-license-faq
    // A large-scale-change added 'default_applicable_licenses' to import
    // all of the 'license_kinds' from "packages_modules_DnsResolver_license"
    // to get the below license kinds:
    //   SPDX-license-identifier-Apache-2.0
    default_applicable_licenses: ["packages_modules_DnsResolver_license"],
}

apex {
    name: "com.android.resolv",
    updatable: true,
    manifest: "manifest.json",
    multilib: {
        first: {
             native_shared_libs: ["libnetd_resolv"],
        },
    },
    key: "com.android.resolv.key",
    certificate: ":com.android.resolv.certificate",

    // Use a custom AndroidManifest.xml used for API targeting.
    androidManifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",

    // Indicates that pre-installed version of this apex can be compressed.
    // Whether it actually will be compressed is controlled on per-device basis.
    compressible: true,

    // IMPORTANT: For the APEX to be installed on Android 10,
    // min_sdk_version should be 29. This enables the build system to make
    // sure the package compatible to Android 10 in two ways:
    // - build the APEX package compatible to Android 10
    //   so that the package can be installed.
    // - build artifacts (lib/javalib/bin) against Android 10 SDK
    //   so that the artifacts can run.
    min_sdk_version: "29",
}

apex_key {
    name: "com.android.resolv.key",
    public_key: "com.android.resolv.avbpubkey",
    private_key: "com.android.resolv.pem",
}

android_app_certificate {
     name: "com.android.resolv.certificate",
     // will use cert.pk8 and cert.x509.pem
     certificate: "testcert",
}
```

From the [docs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/apex) it seems that all I need is to build the `*.apex` from the `Android.bp` but I have no idea what command to run to create the apex binary?

From what I gather, something called [soong](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build) is required to parse and build it from the `Android.bp` file but again I have no idea how to do this from a Mac terminal and nothing seems to come up from web searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of the AOSP tree, which is no longer supported building on macOS officially. The best way is to use a Ubuntu machine to compile the module in AOSP environment.

Comment: Would you mind adding the build command once I am on Ubuntu with soong?
Is it `soong build Android.bp`? What's the actual command once I have the correct environment with soong?

Comment: What are your requirements and what are you trying to achieve, because this is a very broad question as is. Take a look here https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/apex